# Missing signature on UK Tier 5 Youth Mobility Visa

Tags: united-kingdom

Yesterday, I submitted my application form to the Centre and, today, I realised I did not sign the declaration page. I did sign the e-signature and had my fingerprints scanned. Would this cause a refusal to my application?

Comment: No, at most they will reject (not refuse) and get you to sign it at the VSF

Answer (score 1):

According to @GayotFow:

> No, at most they will reject (not refuse) and get you to sign it at the VSF